# How to separate word is .txt. files

Tags: c

Sorry for my bad English, but I really need a help with my problem. Actually, I don't understand how to do attachments here. My teacher give us a task to do program that will write every word from a file, that contains a character that we will accept from the console. For example, like we gave an input 'x' in a console and r program will respond with:

```
x  
\--------------------------------  
xu  
box  
dux  
exl  
fax  
fix  
fox  
kux  
lex  
lux  
mix  
pax  
pix  
sax  
sex  
....
```

But i don't even understand how to sort words in this .txt file. I don't understand why my program is writing some strange symbols and only some time correct words.Please help to write this code.You can dowload file to work with from here, but use only slobvnik_en:https://elearning.tul.cz/mod/resource/view.php?id=177071

Thank you for your help.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
    FILE *read=NULL;
    int i,j=0;
    char *words[101][101];

    if(read=fopen("slovnik_en.txt","r")==NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR FILE");
    }

    for(i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<100;j++)
        {
            words[i][j] = 0;
            printf("%c", words[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("reading\n");

    for(i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<100;j++)
        {
            fscanf(read,"%c",&words[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j <100; j++)
        {

            printf("%c",words[i][j]);

        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OT:  regarding: `printf("ERROR FILE");`  error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`. When the error indication comes from a C library function, should also output (to `stderr`) the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  A simple way to do that is: `perror( "my error message" );`  in the posted code, a failure to open a file for reading is not a recoverable error, so the next statement should be: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );  I.E. do not continue to execute code that expects the input file to be available for reading

Comment: regarding: `if(read=fopen("slovnik_en.txt","r")==NULL)`  Should make the assignment, then make the comparison.  So the statement should be: `if( (read=fopen("slovnik_en.txt","r")) == NULL )`   Also note the insertion of appropriate spaces. for readability

Comment: OT:  `read` is a well known C library function.  It is best to not use variables that are the same as well known C library functions

Comment: regarding: `char *words[101][101];`  This creates a 101 by 101 array of pointers to char.  Not what you want.  Suggest: `char words[101][101];`  which produces an array of 101 arrays of 101 bytes each

Comment: rather than: `for(i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<100;j++)
        {
            words[i][j] = 0;
            printf("%c", words[i][j]);
        }
    }`  suggest using: `char words[101][101] = {'\0'};`

Comment: regarding: `for(i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<100;j++)
        {
            fscanf(read,"%c",&words[i][j]);
        }
    }`  Suggest using: `for( int i=0; i<101; i++ ) { if( fscanf( read, "%100s", words[j] ) != 1 ) {break;} }`  The '100s'  due to appending a NUL byte The '1' because just one format specifier.  The 'break;' to exit the loop when all of input file is read.  The 'int' to limit the scope of the variable 'i'

Comment: OT: Note: the longest word (in english) is `Llanfairpwllgwyngyllgogerychwyrndrobwllllantysiliogogogoch.` which is the name of a welch town.  So the length of each word in the array can be reduced to 60 characters rather than 101 characters

Comment: regarding: `https://elearning.tul.cz/mod/resource/view.php?id=177071`  This will only let us 'guests' access the 'banner' page so we cannot access the file: `slobvnik_en`   Please copy/paste the file into your question

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  amongst other problems, it is missing the `#include` statements for the needed header files.

Comment: regarding: `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`  The parameters `argc` and `argv` are not used.  This results in two warnings from the compiler that can be avoided by using the other valid signature for `main()`  I.E.  `int main( void )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: to avoid 'magic' numbers used `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names.

applying the above and the comments to the question gives the following source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_WORDS 101
#define MAX_WORD_LEN 101


int main( void )
{
    char words[ MAX_WORDS ][ MAX_WORD_LEN ] = {'\0'};

    FILE *fp = fopen( "untitled.c", "r" );
    if( !fp )
    {
        perror( "fopen to read 'slovnix_in.txt' failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    printf("reading\n");

    for(int i=0; i<100; i++ )
    {
        if( fscanf( fp, "%100s",  words[i] ) != 1 )
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    for( int i=0; i<100; i++ )
    {
        if( words[i] )
        {
            printf( "%s", words[i] );
            puts( "" );
        }

        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

then running it against the current source file `untitled.c` results in:

```
reading
#include
<stdio.h>
#include
<stdlib.h>
#define
MAX_WORDS
101
#define
MAX_WORD_LEN
101
int
main(
void
)
{
char
words[
MAX_WORDS
][
MAX_WORD_LEN
]
=
{'\0'};
FILE
*fp
=
fopen(
"untitled.c",
"r"
);
if(
!fp
)
{
perror(
"fopen
to
read
'slovnix_in.txt'
failed"
);
exit(
EXIT_FAILURE
);
}
printf("reading\n");
for(int
i=0;
i<MAX_WORDS;
i++
)
{
if(
fscanf(
fp,
"%100s",
words[i]
)
!=
1
)
{
break;
}
}
for(
int
i=0;
i<MAX_WORDS;
i++
)
{
if(
words[i]
)
{
printf(
"%s",
words[i]
);
puts(
""
);
}
else
{
break;
}
}
return
0;
}
```